# How to compare the equality of two strings in php?

Tags: php, html, css

I want to check the equality of the "$v" and "$formats2". But it gives and error message

> Warning: strcmp() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in C:\xampp\htdocs\playit2\product.php on line 312

Here is my HTML code.

```
$jsqla = mysql_query("select * from products where id='$product_id'") or die(mysql_error());

$jfeta = mysql_fetch_assoc($jsqla);

$formats = explode(";", $jfeta['formats']);

$jsqla2 = mysql_query("select formats from request_list where id='$product_id'") or die(mysql_error());

$jfeta2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($jsqla2);

$formats2 = explode(";", $jfeta2['formats']);

<div class="">
    <?php if($formats2 != "") { ?>
        <?php foreach($formats as $v){ ?>
            <label style="line-height: 1.25em;display: block;width: 100px;margin-right: 10px;float: left;">                         
                <div id="format-id_<?php echo $v?>" <?php if (strcmp($v, $formats2) === 0) { ?> style="border: 1px solid;border-radius: 9px;text-align: center;padding-top: 10px;padding-bottom:10px;padding-left: 3px;padding-right: 3px;border-color: #cccccc;font-family: 'SSemibold'; font-size: 13px; color: #44b7da; background-color: #cccccc;" <?php } else { ?> style="border: 1px solid;border-radius: 9px;text-align: center;padding-top: 10px;padding-bottom:10px;padding-left: 3px;padding-right: 3px;border-color: #cccccc;font-family: 'SSemibold'; font-size: 13px; color: #44b7da;" <?php } ?>>                                
                    <input class="format_cheks" type="radio" value="<?php echo $v; ?>" name="abc" style="visibility:hidden;" id="<?php echo $v ?>" onClick="changeColour(this)"/>
                        <span style="margin:-17px auto auto 0px;display:block;"><?php echo $v; ?></span>                            
                </div>                      
            </label>
        <?php } ?>
    <?php } else { ?>
        <?php foreach($formats as $v){ ?>
            <label style="line-height: 1.25em;display: block;width: 100px;margin-right: 10px;float: left;">                         
                <div id="format-id_<?php echo $v?>" style="border: 1px solid;border-radius: 9px;text-align: center;padding-top: 10px;padding-bottom:10px;padding-left: 3px;padding-right: 3px;border-color: #cccccc;font-family: 'SSemibold'; font-size: 13px; color: #44b7da;">                                
                    <input class="format_cheks" type="radio" value="<?php echo $v; ?>" name="abc" style="visibility:hidden;" id="<?php echo $v ?>" onClick="changeColour(this)"/>
                        <span style="margin:-17px auto auto 0px;display:block;"><?php echo $v; ?></span>                            
                </div>                      
            </label>
        <?php } ?>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: What is it you don't understand about the error? It's pretty straight forward.

Comment: Why do people upvote these questions..

Comment: It would be much easier to help you if you would describe what you are trying to do. Based on what I see it doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
You also use 
if( $val1 === $val2){
   //true part . this === strictly check 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You mistyped `implode` as `explode`. The latter takes a string and produces an array. You likely want the opposite. **UPD**: Oh, you already have a string. Then simply use it as is:

```
- $formats2 = explode(";", $jfeta2['formats']);
+ $formats2 = $jfeta2['formats'];
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I don't think so though, because it would already be a string.

Answer (score 1):

You should pass the `key` as after `explode` it will contain an array.

```
strcmp($v, $formats2[key])
```

[explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)